# Search React/Redux.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am really new to Reac.js/Redux.js and javascript in general. I am trying to learn a new language by actually doing it. I am trying to build a simple app that lets you search for the product. Eventually, I will create additional features that will allow a user to add and to remove the items form the list of products.

So far, I have built two containers: ListOfProd and Search. Everything works except I can’t figure out how filter the list of products based on the search criteria entered by a user. Where would be the best place to implement filter? and What would be the best way to filter the array of objects based on the search criteria? Please let me know how I can improve my code!

Container Search.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreator} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
//import scroll for search
//import Scroll from './components/Search/Scroll';
import SearchBox from '../components/Search/SearchBox';
//import action for search
import {setSearchField} from '../actions/actionSearch';
//list of prod
import ListOfProd from './ListOfProd';

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
 return{
  product: state.product,
  searchField: state.searchField
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return{
  onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
 }
}

class Search extends React.Component{
 render(){
  const {searchField, onSearchChange} = this.props;
  // const filterProduct = this.props.product.filter(product =>{
  //  return product.prod.includes(searchField);
  // })
  return(
   <div className = 'tc'>
    <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange}></SearchBox>
    <ListOfProd></ListOfProd>
   </div>
   )
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

Container ListOfProd.js

```js
// import Component 
// hook it up to data store
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreator} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
//import Search from 'Search';

class ListOfProd extends React.Component {

 createListItems(){
 
   console.log(this.props.product);
   
   return this.props.product.map((product, i) => {
    console.log(this.props.product.prod);
    console.log(this.props.searchField);
   return(
     <li key={i}>{product.prod} {product.price}</li>
    )
  });
  
 }

 render(){
  return(
    <ul>
     {this.createListItems()}
    </ul>
   )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
 return{
  product: state.searchProd.product,
  searchField: state.searchProd.searchField
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListOfProd);
```

Actions

```js
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from '../constants/constants';
export const setSearchField = (text) => ({
 type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
 payload: text
})
```

Reducer ReducerSearch.js

```js
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from '../constants/constants';
import React from 'react';
const initialState = {
 searchField: '',
 product : [
  { 
   id: 1,
   prod: "prod1",
   price: "5"

  },
  {
   id:2,
   prod: "prod2",
   price: "5"
  }
 ]
}

export const searchProd = (state = initialState, action={}) =>{
 console.log(action.payload);
 console.log(action.type);
 switch(action.type){
  case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:{
   console.log(action.payload);
   console.log(state.product);

   return {...state, searchField: action.payload};}
  default: 
   return state;
 }
 
 }
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn/SignIn';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import ListOfProd from './containers/ListOfProd';
import Search from './containers/Search';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Search></Search>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Pleae let me know if you need to see my components.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to implement of filtration is on the key-down event on your text-box.

but before that you have to check your data source and think about your performance, you can set a key limitation or some other limitation.

for your second question, I should say that if your array is in your client use map to have the best performance but you have to get it from a server you can do many things

Comment: You can also debounce the event handler to improve performance and feel.